# Sequence of non-constant integer polynomials whose limit is constant

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, polynomials, sequence-of-function

Does there exist a sequence of non-constant polynomials $\big \{p_{n} \big \}_{n \geq 1}$, each $p_n$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, such that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} p_n =c $$ pointwise on $[0,1]$, where $c$ is a constant?

We can find such polynomials easily on the open interval $(0,1)$, such as $p_n =x^n$, however the closed interval does not seem as simple. The answer seems to be no, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Consider $p_n(x) = x^{2n} - x^n + 1$. Note that all we need to do is find a sequence of polynomials such that $p_n (1) = p_n (0)$ for all sufficiently large $n$, and with the degrees of all monomial terms going off to infinity.

Comment: That condition certainly does not suffice, e.g. it's satisfied by $p_n(x) = x(1 - x)$.

Comment: Whoops, with the degrees of all monomial terms going off to infinity.